# The impossible door!

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

You are standing at the door to a lost temple in Georgia (the former Soviet Republic). You are an expert in lock picking, but there is no keyhole. You then realise that there is a word that will open the door. You tell your friend, who then gives you a piece of paper. "I think the word is on here, but I've got no idea what it means". Looking at it, you think the same. The paper shows this: `{255-36}, {255-32}, {36}, {30} | {255-36}, {255-32}, {36}, {31} | {255-36}, {255-32}, {36}, {32} | {255-36}, {255-32}, {35}, {34}` What does the paper mean in English?

Hint One

> There are three sets of computer codes involved in working this particular puzzle out. That makes the puzzle even more difficult, so I will tell you one of the codes. The third layer of encryption is what a USB Keyboard sends to a computer when a keyboard is pressed.

Hint Two

> [Prem's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16747/the-impossible-door/16859#16859) results in the word "Ghia". That is not actually a word, but a pronunciation. Just apply a bit of logic (and Google Translate), and you should have the word!

Comment: Are the numbers some sort of Soviet code?

Comment: @KritixiLithos  No, but the location is of slight importance...

Comment: What do the numbers mean, Mason?!

Comment: [Above comment was just a reference from Call of Duty.](http://knowyourmeme.com/forums/meme-research/topics/9811-the-numbers-masonwhat-do-they-mean)

Comment: First hint will be added in two days

Comment: The title fits perfectly...

Comment: I suspect it's something to do with colours, maybe 255 = white and 0 = black?

Comment: I'm guessing it's Unicode of some sort.

Comment: @JoeZ It's not Unicode, it's a different set of computer codes. In fact, it is two sets of computer codes...

Comment: @randal'thor - Not colours. Nice idea though.

Comment: @Kslkgh If it's computer codes, maybe the [computer-puzzle] tag?

Comment: @randal'thor I've edited it

Comment: @KritixiLithos The latest update reveals the meaning behind my earlier comment to you.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the China Education and Research Network Center?

Comment: If the answer is მეგობარი, I'm going to laugh.

Comment: @tfitzger No, it does'nt.

Comment: First hint added early because of nobody coming close to the answer and the question doing quite well. This should get you started on working out the puzzle...

Comment: After plenty of scavenging the interwebs, here's a practical way to extract the input_event struct's type/code/value and see what letters they give you. Do you think this would help with this puzzle? (referring to the second answer in the link) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547616/how-can-i-translate-linux-keycodes-from-dev-input-event-to-ascii-in-perl

Comment: The second hint very nearly gives away the answer. The third hint, which will be added later today, will expand on the second hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there seems to be **4 letters in the password, and the common prefix is {255-36} & {255-32}.**

Now, the suffixes (2 per letter) , when converted to key presses, give 7,1 & 7,2 & 7,3 & 6,5. [[ REFER http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-14.html ]]
Probably this means 4 letters 71 , 72 , 73 , 65.

Now many encodings ( Windows-1252/ASCII/UTF/ISO-8859-1 ) all give give 71=G , 72=H , 73=I , 65=A.
[[ OP said unicode is not involved ]]

**Common prefix {255-36} & {255-32} , + GHIA.**

Is this related to car maker GHIA ?
Is this related to "georghia" ?

still thinking . . . .

With the new clues by OP Kslkgh (and the partial answer by Michael Bradfield):
Georgian word "ღია" (pronounced ghia) means OPEN.
So we have 3 possible end-solutions:
**"ghia"**
**"open"**
**"ღია"**

I see that the question mentions "What does the paper mean in English?". So the English translation is most appropriate.
So, the answer must be **"OPEN"**, a command to the DOOR.

Comment: Very nice progress, in fact, your SO nearly there! Just one more step!

Comment: Ghia is (was?) a car designer from Italy.  Not sure if that's the answer or if it helps.

Comment: It is related to Georgia

Comment: The common prefixes that you've found are not intended for the word "Ghia", simply another layer of encryption. They are actually the scan codes for Shift-7 and Shift-3, giving &#. &# is the beginning of a HTML code, and that is what they are: &#71 is G, &#72 is H, &#73 is I and &#65 is A.

Comment: Check the last hint. Think about the door.

Comment: Marked as correct because you have all possible solutions and yes, I did say in English.

Comment: @Kslkgh , ah yes, I see this in your question "What does the paper mean in English?". So that is most appropriate.

Comment: Well, at least it's not FRIEND :-P

Comment: @randal'thor , I think , you probably meant "atleast it is not მეგობარს (megobars)" which is Georgian for friend.

Comment: Another one for all you puzzlers! [Here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16999/the-door-of-death)

Answer (score 1):

Prem has [got](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/16859/5373) as far as the word "ghia" from the given cryptograms, and

> **open** = ghia in the Georgian language

... is this the answer?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I've taken the liberty of editing your answer so that it's a standalone partial answer rather than being more suited to a comment on Prem's answer. You've cracked a crucial part of the puzzle, but someone has already downvoted you, so I stepped in to help. Hope you don't mind :-)