# The door of death!

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

You have been taken prisoner and thrown in a dungeon. You have escaped your cell, are standing in front of two identical doors. One will lead you to freedom, the other to a place where you will die a painful death. Luckily, you have a friend that has agreed to help you. He has smuggled you a code inside of a fake record, but had to encode it in case of them finding out that he was helping their POW to escape, tracing who had sent it and taking him prisoner as well. The message reads this: `38 23 53 48; 38 23 53 50 --- 38 23 53 48; 38 23 54 53 --- 38 23 53 48; 38 23 54 55 --- 38 23 53 49; 38 23 54 55 --- 38 23 53 49; 38 23 53 50` Which door should you go through: Left or Right?

Note 1: This puzzle requires a certain degree of computer knowledge.

Note 2: This CJam program may help: `q'[,65>Dm>_el+_$er`

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this, but 38 23 53 are a leitmotiv in the sequence, for sure not a coincidence.

Comment: The CJam code is a ROT-13 decoder. Try it [here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/) or try a different encoder [here](http://www.decode.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial decoding:

> 38 is ascii decimal for '&', and 23 is ascii hexadecimal for '#', which makes me think every 4 numbers are a html encoded ascii character (starting with "&#").
>
>  53 is ascii decimal for '5' and 48 is ascii decimal for '0', thus the first four numbers are **"&#50"**, or the character **'2'**.

Proceeding the same way with all numbers we get:

> The sequence **24 2A 2C 3C 34**, which is hexadecimal [scan code](http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2keyboard/scancodes2.html) for a PS/2 keyboard (used in one of OP's previous puzzles).
>
> The resulting characters are **E V T U G**.

Then applying ROT-13 results in the answer:

> the **R I G H T** door.

Comment: Getting there...

Comment: @Noel - Hope it is ok that I added a little more detail to your answer ;-)

Comment: Nice job, my next one will be harder and not use any previous methods!

Comment: The next in my series of cryptograms is also a riddle! [Here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17091/a-member-of-my-family-is-killing-me)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an answer without having decoded it:

> Go right. There are 5 blocks of code:
>
> ```
> 38 23 53 48; 38 23 53 50
> 38 23 53 48; 38 23 54 53
> 38 23 53 48; 38 23 54 55
> 38 23 53 49; 38 23 54 55
> 38 23 53 49; 38 23 53 50
> ```
>
> And the word RIGHT has 5 letters.

Comment: Correct answer, wrong method! I'll mark as correct if you get the correct method.

Comment: Well, there was a 50/50 chance of it being right, to be fair. I'm not really sure where to start. There are several repeated chunks and ROT-13 comes into play at some point and that's all I've got.

Comment: @Kslkgh Besides, your last [similar question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/16747/9000) contained a leap of knowledge that I never would have made.

Comment: If I were a prisoner, I probably wouldn't have access to a computer or any kind of reference chart so unless I was intimately familiar with the encoding algorithm, this is probably exactly the kind of thought process I would use to guess.

Comment: @aleppke Yeah, I know. I'm useless with storylines.